# Rxjava2 blockingSubscribe vs subscribe

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java2

I have read the explanation about `blockingSubscribe()` and `subscribe()` but neither I can write nor find an example to see the difference of these. It seems that both of these work the same way. Could someone provide an example of these 2, preferably in Java.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`blockingSubscribe` blocks the current thread and processes the incomnig events on there. You can see this by running some async source:

```java
System.out.println("Before blockingSubscribe");
System.out.println("Before Thread: " + Thread.currentThread());

Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.take(5)
.blockingSubscribe(t -> {
     System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
     System.out.println("Value:  " + t);
});

System.out.println("After blockingSubscribe");
System.out.println("After Thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
```

`subscribe` gives no such confinement and may run on arbitrary threads:

```java
System.out.println("Before subscribe");
System.out.println("Before Thread: " + Thread.currentThread());

Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io())
.concatWith(Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.single()))
.subscribe(t -> {
     System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
     System.out.println("Value:  " + t);
});


System.out.println("After subscribe");
System.out.println("After Thread: " + Thread.currentThread());

// RxJava uses daemon threads, without this, the app would quit immediately
Thread.sleep(3000);

System.out.println("Done");
```

Comment: So, it runs the `Observer`'s actions in the main `Thread` the current function (`main()`) was running?

Comment: @LiTTle, yes, I just checked.